# Camera.PictureCallback stop preview after take a picture

Tags: android, camera

After take a picture using a device with Android API 16, the preview stops working, but when i use a device with Android API 22 the app works fine.

I have this code for take a picture.

```
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    if (fotofile == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Erro ao criar arquivo de mídia, verificar permissões de usuário ");
        return;
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fotofile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

};

That code is called by:

```
 btnFoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFoto);
        btnFoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fotofile  = new File(dir, "foto_" +System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".jpg");

                if (pressed)
                    return;
                pressed = true;

                mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
                    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                        mToast("Foto Capturada!");
                        pressed = false;
                        shootSound();
                    }
                });    
            }
        });
```

My Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

My build.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "centranet.com.br.cameratalao"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

an error ocurr when use

```
mCamera.startPreview(); // After take a picture

E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
            at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
            at centranet.com.br.cameratalao.MainActivity$2$1.onAutoFocus(MainActivity.java:122)
            at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:824)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You have always needed to restart the preview yourself after taking a picture. I am not aware that this has changed in Android 5.2.

Comment: it woks... @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                   mCamera.startPreview();

Comment: I have two devices, one restarts the preview by itself, the other one does nothing. Calling startPreview again does the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing same issue in my Nexus phone (android version 5.1)
once it take the picture stops the preview whereas in Samsung note 3 (Android Version 5.0) it continue to display the preview.
I fixed this

```
onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mCamera.startFaceDetection();
.
.
.
}
```

you need to start face detection again. I don't know why it stops after it starts the preview again.